# command line tool to list all files, with properties and checksum

Tags: files

this command line tool for MsWindows lists all files, with properties and checksum.

http://www.jam-software.de/filelist/

is there an equivalent for unix?

ps: I am aware that I can do a simply script to achieve this; however this question is about finding a tool already implemented. again, please do not tell me how to implement this by myself. I will do this if such a tool does not already exist.

---

**Update**

I finally agree with lain and lVlint67's comment that it's ok to implement my own script (even if there are some corner cases with the current script):

dstat

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
  echo "dstat <file>"
  exit 1
fi

HASH="                                "
if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
  HASH=`md5 -q "$1"`
fi

FILENAME=$(basename "$1")
EXT="${FILENAME##*.}"

FILENAME_ESCAPED=$(echo $FILENAME | sed -e "s/%/%%/g")
EXT_ESCAPED=$(echo $EXT | sed -e "s/%/%%/g")

stat -t "%F %T" -f "%HT%t%Sp%t%Su%t%Sg%t%Sm%t%SB%t%14z%t$HASH%t$FILENAME_ESCAPED%t%SY%t$EXT_ESCAPED%t%N" "$1"
```

use as follows:

```
$ find . -exec dstat {} \;
```

and I get a result such as:

```
Regular File    -rw-r--r--      david   staff   2013-11-09 01:33:24     2013-11-09 01:33:24              14787  c3a7afd9e3cf89543352ee58e26cfb10        Invoice_41010102336895558_6601081486112013.pdf          pdf     ./accounting/files/Invoice_41010102336895557_6601081486112013.pdf
Regular File    -rw-r--r--      david   staff   2013-09-01 00:41:05     2013-09-01 00:41:05              13636  55b47d2a41d5d6a072439ef2dabacac4        Invoice_41010102336895558_6601108809092013.pdf          pdf     ./accounting/files/Invoice_41010102336895557_6601108809092013.pdf
...
```

Comment: It's a simple one liner with find and $checksum_program_of_choice anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has regular GNU tools I would not bother installing some random third party software... just deploy the following:

```
alias filelist='find ./ -type f -exec ls -la {} \; -exec md5sum {}  \;'
cd /tmp; filelist
```